# why the size of List in not incrementing

Tags: asp.net

I create dynamically checkboxes all of them with assigned checkedChanged event, which on postback  I recreate and everything is working except one thing;

- I should  save the value of checked checkboxes in a List . But it seems that on each postBack event (every time I check a checkbox) the elements of the list are lost although `myche` is a global variable of type List ;

lblProba.Text +="in if clause; element count="+ myche.Count.ToString();

gives me  **1** every time I check a checkbox

```
protected void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            myche.Add(chk.InputAttributes["value"].ToString());
            lblProba.Text +="in if clause; element count="+ myche.Count.ToString();


        }

        else 
        {
            lblProba.Text += "enering else;element count:"+myche.Count.ToString();




        }

            lblProba.Text += "Final length" + myche.Count.ToString();
            for (int t = 0; t < myche.Count; t++)
        { 
            Session["chk"]+= myche[t]; 

        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web application you can think of every postback as leading to a completely new start of your application. It doesn't remember any state, all the objects are being instantiated as if it's the first time your application is running.

ASP.NET tries to hide this fact by employing things like ViewState etc., but nevertheless your server-side objects don't live beyond a single request/response cycle.

To carry state through multiple requests you could store intermediate values in the [`Session`](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/) variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check on the [lifecycle of ASP.NET pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Each time you call a page, ASP.NET creates a new instance of the page, loads it with any Viewstate data (if this is a postback) and passes control to your Load event. Once the page sends the response to the browser, the instance is destroyed.

ASP.NET manages ViewState for the statically created controls automatically. You will have to ensure that any data required to rebuild and populate your dynamic controls is saved in the ViewState and used to rebuild them in your Loaded event.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your list e.g. in Session object to avoid losing it on every postback.